# MySQL Group Concat on a derived table

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have a derived table and I would like to do a `GROUP_CONCAT()` on the derived table while still getting all the columns of the derived table

For example, I have a table called patient and one called appointment, and I would like to get a GROUP_CONCAT() of appointment IDs per patient with given criteria.

Right now I am doing something like this:

```
SELECT
  t1.*
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      patient.name,
      patient.ptid,
      appointment.date
    FROM
      patient
      LEFT JOIN appointment ON appointment.patient_id = patient.ptid
     /* a **lot** of filters, additional joins, etc*/
  ) t1
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
      GROUP_CONCAT(appointment.appt_id) appointments,
      patient.ptid
    FROM
      patient
      LEFT JOIN appointment ON appointment.patient_id = patient.ptid
    GROUP BY
      patient.id
  ) t2 
  ON t1.ptid = t2.ptid
```

But the problem is that the GROUP_CONCAT() doesn't take any of the filters or anything else from the first derived table into consideration. There can also be upwards of 20 million appointment records so I feel like the additional join is just doing unnecessary work...Any advice on how to work around this? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried an `INNER JOIN` between `t1` and `t2`?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

I think the second subquery should be like this. Because I think we don't need to join tables there.

```sql
    SELECT
      patient_id, 
      GROUP_CONCAT(appointment.appt_id) appointments,
    FROM
      appointment
    GROUP BY
      patient_id
```